# How to extend an abstract class with Generics in Java?

Tags: java

I'm hoping to learn a bit about generics in Java through this question.

I made the following abstract class, which I would like to extend:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public abstract class TableCellWithButton<DataType, InfoType> extends TableCell<DataType, InfoType> {
    final Button button;

    public TableCellWithButton(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(
            InfoType item,
            boolean empty
    ) {
        super.updateItem(
                item,
                empty
        );
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            button.setOnAction(event -> {
                buttonClickHandler(this);
            });
            setGraphic(button);
            setText(null);
        }
    }

    abstract void buttonClickHandler(TableCell<DataType, InfoType> cell);
}
```

However, when I try to extend the function in the following manner...

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class ActiveLoansTableCellWithButton extends TableCellWithButton<Debt, String> {

    @Override
    public void buttonClickHandler(TableCell<Debt, String> cell) {
        // Trying to extend here...
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Class 'ActiveLoansTableCellWithButton' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'buttonClickHandler(TableCell<DataType, InfoType>)' in 'TableCellWithButton'

**Clearly, I'm not overriding my `buttonClickHandler` method in `TableCellWithButton`. What am I missing that is stopping me from successfully overriding my method?**

**Screenshot of my IDE:**

[image]

Comment: "*Clearly, I'm not overriding my `buttonClickHandler` method in `TableCellWithButton`*" - Does the compiler also complain about the `@Override`-annotation? If not, then you are overriding the method correctly. Could it be that there is (are) further abstract method(s) in `TableCell` that you need to implement?

Comment: @Turing85 Yep the compiler and Intellij are both complaining at me about the same thing. I've just updated my post with the complete error message to show that it appears I'm definitely not overriding correctly :(

Comment: @Turing85 just added a screenshot of my IDE containing the code for some extra proof :)

Comment: make the method public (or protected) in the abstract class `TableCellWithButton`. As both classes are in different packages, the concrete class can't 'see' the abstract method

Comment: @k5_ yep - thats the solution to my noob question! Thanks so much for finding that so quickly :)

Comment: @k5_ you may want to post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `buttonClickHandler` in `TableCellWithButton` is package private (has no visiblity modifier). So the method can only be overriden with classes in the same package.

In the screenshort provided, both classes are in different packages.

So either move both classes to the same package, or adjust the visbility of the method to public (or protected)